# vb.net MissingPrimaryKeyException even though PK is set

Tags: vb.net, primary-key, rows

I'm trying to find the row number in table `SPOT` for primary key 1. The pk has been set in the table design (there is a key next to the column called ID) but I get `MissingPrimaryKeyException` error. Do I need to add more lines of code stating which column is the pk?

```
     Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim table As DataTable = New DataTable("SPOT")
        Dim foundRow As DataRow = table.Rows.Find("1")

    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: dataset][image: SPOT table]

Comment: can you show your query to load table in `datatable` ? and if possible snapshot of table design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
Private Sub SetPrimaryKeys()
   ' Create a new DataTable and set two DataColumn objects as primary keys.
   Dim table As DataTable = new DataTable()
   Dim keys(2) As DataColumn
   Dim column  As DataColumn

   ' Create column 1.
   column = New DataColumn()
   column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
   column.ColumnName= "FirstName"

   ' Add the column to the DataTable.Columns collection.
   table.Columns.Add(column)
   ' Add the column to the array.
   keys(0) = column

   ' Create column 2 and add it to the array.
   column = New DataColumn()
   column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
   column.ColumnName = "LastName"
   table.Columns.Add(column)

   ' Add the column to the array.
   keys(1) = column

   ' Set the PrimaryKeys property to the array.
   table.PrimaryKey = keys
End Sub`enter code here`
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.primarykey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but table ``SPOT`` already exists in the database and dataset, has data and has a pk (key symbol next to first column). Do I need to create a new table?

Comment: Oh, I was referring to the code you posted. So you are working with typed data set. I would check the xsd file to be sure if there is a primary key on the table and how many columns participate in that primary key. Strange this is, as Yoda would say....

Comment: I'm very new to Visual Studio and vb.net, so maybe I'm doing this totally wrong. I have a dataset and SPOT is one of the tables in the dataset. There is a key next to column ID so I'm pretty sure the pk has been set. Can  you take a look at the screenshot attached to the question and let me know if I'm missing something?

Comment: Have you tried to locate the row using something like Dim rows as DataRow() = Table.Select( String.Format( "Id = {0}", 1 ) ) to see what happens?

Comment: By the way I don't see something strange.

Comment: no I've just used code scraped off the net. Getting a row has to be easier than this? I reckon there is a simple line of code missing or the data structure is wrong.